# How to get nohup + tail to NOT add newlines to carriage returns?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nohup

I use the Keras package, which offers a nice "progress bar" feature to stdout when you're training.  As it updates the bar, it uses carriage returns with no newlines so that the bar stays on the same line (at the bottom of the terminal) as it gets longer and longer.

But when I run via `nohup myprogram &`, and I try to follow the run using `tail -f nohup.out`, it adds newlines to every carriage return, so I end up seeing an extremely long output of every state of every progress bar on hundreds of new lines, instead of just having each bar take up one line:  i.e. nohup or tail is adding newlines to the carriage returns (CRs).

How I can disable this, so that CRs remain just CRs?

I couldn't find any relevant parameters in the man pages for nohup or tail.  Wondering if this has to do with the difference between running in an interactive shell vs. ...whatever state nohup uses. Tried searching on this, found several SO posts about *adding* newlines to CRs, but none about *not* adding them.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, running bash.

Comment: Neither `nohup` nor `tail` do that. They just don't. Something else is doing it; for example, many programs will vary their output depending on whether it goes to a terminal or not.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks, your comment gave me the impetus to look elsewhere: looks like this an issue people are having elsewhere in Keras.  https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5906

Comment: Please close your Q as it will not be useful to programmers. Glad you have found out more about your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @AlexP Submit that as an answer and I’ll accept it

Comment: @shellter I disagree with your assessment that this wouldn’t be useful to other programmers. I would’ve loved to find a post like this to inspire me to look in the library I’m using instead of wasting time searching for a nohup/tail/shell solution.   I’ll accept AlexP’s answer once he makes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `nohup` nor `tail` do that. They just don't.

Many programs will vary their output depending on whether it goes to a terminal or not. Maybe the application you are using does this too.

Comment: Yep, I just tested and it's not `tail`. Good call. (in fact `tail -f` won't output anything until it receives the `'\n'` -- it is line-buffered, but it isn't the culprit here)